# How to use ckeditor with dexterity custom type in Plone 4.1 / 4.2?

Tags: ckeditor, plone, dexterity

I'm trying to use `ckeditor` instead `TinyMCE` in my custom dexterity type, but I'm always getting the empty editor textarea.

I changed the default editors to `ckeditor` and already installed `z3c.formwidget.ckeditor`.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
text = RichText(title=_(u"Foo"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know but I get the same thing for now... Invastigating...